# How to migrate Sign in with Apple credentials from App Clip to parent app using Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, firebase, keychain, sign-in-with-apple, apple-appclips

I'm using Sign in with Apple in the app together with Firebase Auth. It works as expected.

I'm also developing an App Clip. It works the same as in the parent app, but I want to migrate credentials when the user migrates to the parent app. That's all good but in order to sign in user to Auth, it requires `token` in order to create an `OAuthProvider.credential`.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/making_data_available_to_the_app_clip_s_corresponding_app#3599736) says that we should store credential `userId` to the shared user defaults. But I don't want to store the credential in here.

There is also an [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on) to implement cross-app authentication using shared keychain, which unfortunately is not available for App Clips.

Does anyone have a clue how to migrate Sign in with Apple credentials from App Clip to the parent app using Firebase Auth?

Comment: Apple has mentioned clearly that the only way to communicate between the App Clip and parent full app once installed is through the shared storage. I'm curious  to find out if you find a workaround

Comment: I'm well aware of that but I'm hesitant to put credentials into shared user defaults. It would be great if we could leverage a shared keychain, but that is also a no-go from Apple.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is a limitation. Still, in their documentation Apple recommends to store only the user Id which is less sensitive, never the password. Good luck

Comment: Hypothetically you might be able to use a shared Keychain entry to share some token data? Not sure if possible on App Clip though. As long as the App Clip and the App are from the same team or something, you might be able to arrange something like that?